# Cannot append function into an array because of attribute 'split'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, split

My task here is first split a given string into two parts, the year and month. For example, if the input is `ex1_b("2000,12")`, the function should return `2000-Dec`.

And then I want to keep the new format of the data and insert into an array. Then after I will try to insert it inside a DataFrame. But I have problems with appending the results of the function.

The function itself is working, and outputs correctly, but when I try to append the results inside an array, it gives out the following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[460], line 4
      1 new_format = []
      3 for i in range (0, len(date)):
----> 4     new_format.append(ex1_b(date[i]))
      6 print(new_format)

Cell In[459], line 15, in ex1_b(date)
     11 f_date = date_val[date_val.columns[0]]
     12 # f_date = date_val[date_val.columns[0]]
     13 # s_value = date_val.iloc[:,1].values
---> 15 years =  int(date.split(",")[0]) # even if I change to str() no change
     16 months = int(date.split(",")[1])
     17 # matrix_b.to_csv("matrix-B.csv", index=False)
     18 # input = [int(i) for i in date.split(",")]
     19 # input = [int(i) for i in f_date.str.split(",")]

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can I solve this?

My code

```
date_val = {'date' : [],
            'value' : []}

for i in range(0, 25):
    for j in range(0, 12):
        month = str(j+1).zfill(2)
        date_val['date'].append( str(year[i]) + "," + month)
        date_val['value'].append(df.loc[i,j+1])
        date.append(str(year[i]) + "," + month)
        value.append(df.loc[i,j+1])
date_val = pd.DataFrame(date_val)



mon = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
          'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
def ex1_b(date:str):
    f_date = date_val[date_val.columns[0]] #IN CASE I WILL NEED IT

    years =  int(date.split(",")[0])
    months = int(date.split(",")[1])

    if(years<2022 or years>1996 or months>0 or months<13):
        year_month = f"{str(years)}-{mon[months-1]}"

    return year_month
print(ex1_b("2000,12")) #WORKS

# THE PROBLEM
new_format = []
for i in range (0, len(date)):
    new_format.append(ex1_b(date[i]))

print(new_format)
```

Comment: Where is `date` defined? The one in global scope.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: @Axe319 I edited and added nearly whole code

Comment: You have `date.append()` and `value.append()`, but you never define these variables.

Comment: Avoid reusing variable names. It's confusing that you initially define `date_val` as a dictionary, then redefine it as a dataframe.

Comment: Why do you keep using `j+1` instead of just using `for j in range(1, 13):`?

Comment: Please show the full traceback. I don't see how that could be happening in the last `for` loop, since the `date` list contains strings, not integers. Unless the list wasn't empty before the first `for` loop.

Comment: Take a look (`print(date)`) at `date` in the # THE PROBLEM section. At least one of its elements must be an `int`. Also provide the full traceback rather than the error, it often has useful information.

Comment: @Barmar if I define them it will just add up to the loads of variables that I already created, so I hesitated a bit, and about the j+1 part, the instruction were given in that way, so I had to

Comment: @Barmar and I edited and added the full traceback, even if I change and make ```years =  str(date.split(",")[0]) ``` still no change in error

Comment: You still haven't shown how you initialize the `date` list. According to the error, the list contains an integer, that can't be coming from the loop at the beginning of the code snippet.